# Does (Array/List/Seq).groupBy maintain sort order within groups?

Tags: f#

Does `groupBy` guarantee that sort order is preserved in code like the following?

```
x
|> Seq.sortBy (fun (x, y) -> y)
|> Seq.groupBy (fun (x, y) -> x)
```

By preserving sort order, I mean can we guarantee that within each grouping by `x`, the result is still sorted by `y`.

This is true for simple examples,

```
[(1, 3);(2, 1);(1, 1);(2, 3)]
|> Seq.sortBy (fun (x, y) -> y)
|> Seq.groupBy (fun (x, y) -> x)
// seq [(2, seq [(2, 1); (2, 3)]); (1, seq [(1, 1); (1, 3)])]
```

I want to make sure there are no weird edge cases.

Comment: Well, it's pretty easy to test. You have all the code

Comment: It's easy to test special cases, but unclear if this generalizes. To clarify, I am wondering if there are edge cases that I should be worried about. Typical scenarios are sorting on DateTime or NodaTime.LocalTime, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation doesn't say explicitly (except through the example), but [the implementation does preserve the order of the original sequence](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/8f02ecb0b79947e67e6a0ef9c482d167baf17696/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L1448). It would be quite surprising if it didn't: the equivalent functions in other languages that I am aware of do.

Comment: Thank you. Understanding the source you link to appears to require understanding the implementation of .Net dictionaries. So prev.Add is adding the element to the *end* of the "list" of items that represent the value of what the dictionary returns for that key? Is this how we know that the implementation preserves the order within each grouping? (Intuitively, if the implementation just loops through the sequence (like the seq |> iter line says) and concatenates to the end of the grouping as it builds the group up then sort order should be preserved. I'm just not good at reading this source.

Comment: It doesn't require understanding the implementation of dictionaries. `prev` is the value, which has the type `ResizeArray<'T>`, which you can [see](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353447.aspx) is an alias for `System.Collections.Generic.List<'T>` (to avoid confusion with F# lists). You do need to be aware that `List.Add` adds an element to the end of the list, and then the order preservation follows in the way you describe.

Answer (score 8):

What do you mean by preserving sort order? `Seq.groupBy` changes the type of the sequence, so how can you even meaningfully compare *before* and *after*?

For a given `xs` of the type `seq<'a * 'b>`, the type of the expression `xs |> Seq.sortBy snd` is `seq<'a * 'b>`, whereas the type of the expression `xs |> Seq.sortBy snd |> Seq.groupBy fst` is `seq<'a * seq<'a * 'b>>`. Thus, whether or not the answer to the question is *yes* or *no* depends on what you mean by *preserving the sort order*.

As @Petr wrote in the comments, it's easy to test this. If you're worried about special cases, write a **Property** using [FsCheck](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck) and see if it generalises:

```
open FsCheck.Xunit
open Swensen.Unquote

[<Property>]
let isSortOrderPreserved (xs : (int * int) list) =
    let actual = xs |> Seq.sortBy snd |> Seq.groupBy fst

    let expected = xs |> Seq.sortBy snd |> Seq.toList
    expected =! (actual |> Seq.map snd |> Seq.concat |> Seq.toList)
```

In this property, I've interpreted the property of sort order preservation to mean that if you subsequently concatenate the grouped sequences, the sort order is preserved. Your definition may be different.

Given this particular definition, however, running the property clearly demonstrates that **the property doesn't hold:**

```
Falsifiable, after 6 tests (13 shrinks) (StdGen (1448745695,296088811)):
Original:
[(-3, -7); (4, -7); (4, 0); (-4, 0); (-4, 7); (3, 7); (3, -1); (-5, -1)]
Shrunk:
[(3, 1); (3, 0); (0, 0)]

---- Swensen.Unquote.AssertionFailedException : Test failed:

[(3, 0); (0, 0); (3, 1)] = [(3, 0); (3, 1); (0, 0)]
false
```

Here we see that if the input is `[(3, 1); (3, 0); (0, 0)]`, the grouped sequence doesn't preserve the sort order (which isn't surprising to me).

---

Based on the updated question, here's a property that examines that question:

```
[<Property(MaxTest = 10000)>]
let isSortOrderPreservedWithEachGroup (xs : (int * int) list) =
    let actual = xs |> Seq.sortBy snd |> Seq.groupBy fst

    let expected =
        actual
        |> Seq.map (fun (k, vals) -> k, vals |> Seq.sort |> Seq.toList)
        |> Seq.toList
    expected =!
        (actual |> Seq.map (fun (k, vals) -> k, Seq.toList vals) |> Seq.toList)
```

This property does, indeed, hold:

```
Ok, passed 10000 tests.
```

You should still consider carefully whether you want to rely on behaviour that isn't documented, since it could change in later incarnations of F#. Personally, I'd adopt a piece of advice from [the Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Explicit is better than implicit.

BTW, the reason for all that conversion to F# lists is because lists have structural equality, while sequences don't.

Comment: To clarify: By preserving sort order, I meant if you sort (x, y) tuples by y, then group by x, will the tuples within each x grouping still be sorted by y.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful answer, I should have been more clear about  what I meant by "preserving sort order".

Comment: Thanks, I agree on explicit being better. Was being explicit originally but sort inside loop was causing performance problems. Probably explicit + different algorithm is the solution.

Comment: Great answer, and point about explicit better than implicit. I accepted the other because the present source code (after reading carefully) gave the deterministic answer. Nonetheless I upvoted your answer too because it is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

Who cares. Instead of sorting and then grouping, just group and then sort and the ordering is guaranteed even if the F# implementation of groupBy eventually changes:

`x
|> Seq.groupBy (fun (x, y) -> x)
|> Seq.map (fun (k, v) -> k, v |> Seq.sortBy (fun (x, y) -> y))`