# Does Seq.groupBy preserve order within groups?

Tags: f#, sequences

I want to group a sequence and then take the first occurrence of each element in the group.  When I try this

```
Seq.groupBy f inSeq
|> Seq.map (fun (k,s) -> (k,s|>Seq.take 1|>Seq.exactlyOne))
```

I find that sometimes I get a different element from s. Is this expected?

Comment: Yes, I should use Seq.head in the second line, but I wanted to share the code I'm working with verbatim. :)

Comment: Can you isolate the cases when this happens?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does (Array/List/Seq).groupBy maintain sort order within groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022302/does-array-list-seq-groupby-maintain-sort-order-within-groups)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [source of the `groupBy` implementation](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L1429) -
here's the relevant bit:

```
// Build the groupings

seq |> iter (fun v ->
    let safeKey = keyf v
    let mutable prev = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
    match dict.TryGetValue (safeKey, &prev) with
    | true -> prev.Add v
    | false ->
        let prev = ResizeArray ()
        dict.[safeKey] <- prev
        prev.Add v)
```

It iterates through the source array and adds the values to the corresponding list for the key. The order of subsequences is directly affected by the order of the input sequence. For the same input sequence, we can expect `groupBy` to return identical output sequences. This is how tests are coded for `groupBy`.

If you're seeing variations in the resulting sequences, check the input sequence.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I expected, but for some reason I received something different. Unfortunately, now I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @RobertSim Must have been a case of "Works on My Machine™" in reverse.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is expected. Sequences (`seq`) aren't guaranteed to be [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). You can define a sequence that will yield different values every time you iterate over them. If you call `Seq.take 1` twice, you can get different results.

Consider, as an example, this sequence:

```
open System

let r = Random ()
let s = seq { yield r.Next(0, 9) }
```

If you call `Seq.take 1` on that, you may get different results:

```
> s |> Seq.take 1;;
val it : seq<int> = seq [4]
> s |> Seq.take 1;;
val it : seq<int> = seq [1]
```

Using `Seq.head` isn't going to help you either:

```
> s |> Seq.head;;
val it : int = 2
> s |> Seq.head;;
val it : int = 6
```

If you want to guarantee deterministic behaviour, use a `List` instead.

Comment: ... or in some cases, one can use `Seq.cache` to 'pin' the `seq` (but the closing line re modeling things as they should be holds)